# Calculation of Neurons in GPT-2: Understanding the Methodology

Tags: gpt

In a recent update from OpenAI, they mentioned the discovery of N neurons in their GPT-2 model. This finding raises the question: how did they arrive at this calculation? In their publication, they did not explicitly mention the methodology behind determining the number of neurons.

Upon further investigation, I came across a set of formulas that are commonly used to estimate the number of neurons and parameters in transformer-based models like GPT-2. These formulas, although not specifically mentioned by OpenAI, provide a good starting point for understanding the calculation.

The formulas are as follows:

$$\text{Neurons}= H * A * L$$
$$\text{Parameters} = A * (H^2 / A) * L$$

Here, "H" represents the hidden size, "A" refers to the number of attention heads in the model, and "L" denotes the number of layers in the model.

It is important to note that these formulas make certain assumptions about the model architecture. They assume that the number of neurons in each attention head and layer is constant, which might not be the case in practice. Additionally, they do not account for other architectural elements specific to transformer models, such as positional encodings and feed-forward networks.

While the provided formulas offer a general approach for estimating the number of neurons, it is essential to consider the specific model architecture and consult the actual implementation details for more accurate calculations.

Considering this, can anyone shed more light on how OpenAI arrived at the calculation of N neurons in their GPT-2 model? Has OpenAI explicitly mentioned their methodology or provided additional insights into the process? Any further clarification on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your input and expertise!

Comment: The equation for Parameters doesn't seem right, `∗(2/)∗` is same as `(2)∗`

Answer (score 0):

#### Total Neurons Formula

The formula for **Total Neurons** represents the total number of "neurons" in GPT-2 XL. Each "neuron" corresponds to an individual unit or processing element within the model. The formula is given by:

$$\text{Total Neurons} = L * 5H$$

- **L**: Number of transformer layers.
- **H**: Hidden size of the transformer layers.

Let's break down the technical steps:

1. Each transformer layer has a hidden size denoted by H. This hidden size represents the number of dimensions in the hidden state of the transformer layer.
2. In each transformer layer, the feed-forward network is applied independently to each position. The feed-forward network has an input size of H and an output size of F. In GPT-2, the output size F is chosen to be 4 times the hidden size H.
3. Now, let's consider the number of neurons in each transformer layer. In a transformer layer, the total number of neurons is the sum of the number of neurons in the self-attention mechanisms and the number of neurons in the feed-forward network.
4. In the self-attention mechanisms, the number of neurons can be approximated as H, which is the hidden size of the transformer layer.
5. In the feed-forward network, the number of neurons can be approximated as F, which is the output size of the feed-forward network. Since F is chosen to be 4 times H, we have F = 4H.
   Considering these approximations, the total number of neurons in each transformer layer can be calculated as H + F = H + 4H = 5H.
6. Finally, to get the total number of neurons in the entire model, we multiply the number of neurons in each layer (5H) by the number of transformer layers (L), resulting in the formula L * 5H.

---

For example, if we consider H = 1280 and L = 48, we can calculate the total number of neurons as follows:

Total Neurons = 48 * 5 * 1280 = [307,200 neurons](https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/neuron-explainer/paper/index.html#sec-interesting-neurons)

This means that GPT-2 XL, with 48 transformer layers and a hidden size of 1280, has a total of 307,200 "neurons".

#### Total Parameters Formula

The formula for **Total Parameters** represents the total number of trainable parameters in GPT-2 XL. Parameters are the learnable variables in the model that are adjusted during the training process. The formula is given by:

$$\text{Total Parameters} = 7 * H^2 * L + 4 * H * L$$

- **L**: Number of transformer layers.
- **H**: Hidden size of the transformer layers.

The formula consists of two terms:

1. The term **7 * H^2 * L** represents the number of parameters associated with the self-attention mechanisms. It considers the hidden size of the transformer layers (H) squared and multiplies it by 7 to account for the query, key, and value linear transformations. The result is then multiplied by the number of transformer layers (L).
2. The term **4 * H * L** represents the number of parameters associated with the feed-forward networks. It considers the hidden size of the transformer layers (H) multiplied by 4, which is derived from the assumption that the hidden size of the feed-forward networks is 4 times the hidden size of the transformer layers. The result is then multiplied by the number of transformer layers (L).

---

For example, if we consider H = 1280 and L = 48, we can calculate the total number of parameters as follows:

Total Parameters = 7 * 1280^2 * 48 + 4 * 1280 * 48 = 1,591,101,440

This means that GPT-2 XL, with a hidden size of 1280 and 48 transformer layers, has a total of 1,591,101,440 trainable parameters.

These formulas provide insights into the complexity and capacity of GPT-2 XL, quantifying the number of "neurons" and trainable parameters based on the given values of H and L.

Comment: Please don't use the answer field for updates; rather update your question with your attempt.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. Thanks!